# CMake the compiler is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to setup `cmake` on Windows 11 x64.

I'm using `MinGW Makefiles` and `make.exe` for the building. I installed the compiler and `make` using `Cygwin`. The compiler is a native compiler.

My CMakeLists.txt contains the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(hello CXX)
add_executable(hello main.cpp)
```

Inside the `build` directory I run the following command:
`cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=make ..`

The output I get:

```
    -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/cygwin64/bin/g++.exe
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/cygwin64/bin/g++.exe - broken
    CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:62 (message):
      The C++ compiler
    
        "C:/cygwin64/bin/g++.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.
 It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/username/Projects/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):make -f Makefile cmTC_2f478/fast && make  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_2f478.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_2f478.dir/build
    'mTC_2f478.dir' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    make: *** [Makefile:126: cmTC_2f478/fast] Error 1





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/username/Projects/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/username/Projects/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The path the compiler is installed is in `PATH`.

```
> where.exe g++
C:\cygwin64\bin\g++.exe
```

Also I tried building a `hello world` using `g++.exe main -o main.cpp` and worked fine.

Comment: **Cygwin** is not a **MinGW**. Either use cygwin compiler with "normal" Windows generator (e.g. Ninja), or find (other) MinGW compiler for work under MinGW.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That worked! I was not able to install MinGW64 on my system and thought it was the same.